# Fixed conky pane position regardless of the monitors available

Tags: multiple-monitors, conky

I have a conky pane that displays my laptop status on the desktop. My conky configuration works great when I'm only using the laptop's display, but it changes position if I connect a second monitor to the laptop. I would like to keep the conky pane in my laptop's display regardless if I connect a second monitor or not. The pane should be aligned to the right margin of the screen in the middle (see first pic).

However, this is not what happens with the current config. If conky starts running with both monitors connected, the pane moves to the right, and it gets cropped out of the laptop monitor (see second pic). If conky starts with only the laptop monitor, and then I connect the second monitor, the pane moves slightly up and to the right (see third pic). In the 2nd and 3rd pics you can see the part of the conky pane that extends out of the screen. However, I cannot see that part IRL because it is outside my monitor. One last thing, the second monitor is set to display on top of the laptop's monitor.

I thought the settings below did what I wanted, but I was wrong :( Where did I messed up?

```
xinerama_head = 0,
alignment = 'middle_right',
gap_x = 0,
gap_y = 0,
```

Here is the whole `conky.config` field in my configuration file:

```
conky.config = { 
    update_interval = 1,
    cpu_avg_samples = 2,
    net_avg_samples = 2,
    out_to_console = false,
    override_utf8_locale = true,
    double_buffer = true,
    no_buffers = true,
    text_buffer_size = 32768,
    imlib_cache_size = 0,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_type = 'normal',
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_argb_value = 100,
    own_window_hints = 'undecorated,below,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager',
    border_inner_margin = 5,
    border_outer_margin = 0,
    xinerama_head = 0,
    alignment = 'middle_right',
    gap_x = 0,
    gap_y = 0,
    draw_shades = false,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_borders = false,
    draw_graph_borders = false,
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'Ubuntu Mono:size=12',
    xftalpha = 0.8,
    uppercase = false,
    default_color = 'white',
    own_window_colour = '#000000',
    minimum_width = 300, minimum_height = 0,
};
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Desktop on the laptop.

Thanks for the help :)

[image: 1. Single monitor conky rendering]

[image: 2. Dual monitor rendering when conky starts with 2 monitors connected]

[image: 3. Dual monitor rendering when conky starts with 1 monitor connected, and the second monitor is connected later on]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me after having the same issue like you:

```
own_window_type = 'desktop',
alignment = 'top_right',
gap_x = 0,
gap_y = 50, ##### for position underneath top bar...
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I'm not able to confirm this works for me anymore. I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04, and I changed the Conky configuration to something different. However, I'll take your word for it, and I'll mark it as the answer with that caveat.